# Python/SQL: create table name with variables extracted from a tab delimited file

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlite

Is there a way to create the table name (of a SQL DB) with variables extracted from the header of a tab delimited file ? 
I have try this:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('cur_test.sq3')
cur = conn.cursor()
#Create a 'test.txt' file for that example
test = open('test.txt', 'w')
test.write('a\t1\t2\n')
test.close()
#REMEMBER: header of test.txt = a   1   2 (tab delimited)
with open('test.txt') as f: 
    header = f.readline().rstrip("\n") #Extract the header
    a, b, c = header.split("\t")  #Split it into variable
    b, c = int(b), int(c)  #Convert some string into integer
    req = "CREATE TABLE test (%s TEXT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER)" #I need help here
    cur.execute(req, (a, b, c))
conn.commit()
```

Obviously the `cur.execute` fail because of the wrong syntax for calling the variables:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after the string on your commented line:

```
% (a, b, c)
```

Better yet, read about the newer style of string formatting: https://mkaz.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/

And then, generally speaking, strictly avoid using untrusted string input to build SQL statements.

Comment: I get a new error `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "1": syntax error`. It look like we can't pass number (i've try with string number and get the same error ?! because of the `%s` maybe). BUT, it work well with strict string like 'a','one','two' for that example. And with your answer i find a way with a classic .format cmd : `cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test ({0:s} TEXT, {1:s} INTEGER, {2:s} INTEGER)".format(a, b, c))` Finally: with that example, how can we avoid using untrusted string input to build SQL statements ? –

Comment: Generally, for Python, you pass parameters to the cursor.execute() method, per the DB-API PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249  Also see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects